# best way to append huge data to dataframe

Tags: pandas, memory, append

```
while 1:  
    lines = cur.fetchmany(pageSize)  
    if len(lines)==0:  
        break 
    df.append(lines)# method1:df never change
    df = df.append(lines)# method2:df change but too many memory used.
```

I load a table with 40 columns and about 2M records into a df and I only have 8G memory.Now I use a csv file solution but it want more time.
I wonder is it possible there is a way like method1, Pandas really only append the data to the dataframe without any copy?

Comment: Firstly [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) is not in place this is why `df.append(lines)` doesn't modify `df`, it returns the modified df. Secondly iteratively growing a df a line at a time is non-performant. what is `cur`? is this a DB cursor? pandas supports reading from a db. Also do you need to read the entire data into memory?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to append to? Just a dataframe in memory, or a CSV? A database? The answer will differ based on your response.

Comment: I download the 2Mx40columns table to a csv file and then load it to a df, my memory used 33%...If I load directly form db by the mothod2, my memory used 80%...I wonder if there is a way like method1, after I directly load the df from db, my memory used same as 33%. Thanks!

Comment: I manually delete all other python object and run the gc, but the memory is still 80% used.